# How to make speaking clock (via cron and festival tts) work while playing music

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, cron, 15.04

I switched to Linux since last 11 months, I am on Ubuntu 15.04, I have learned to use Cron for various tasks.

I use Cron to announce time via festival TTS (using mbrolla voice) hourly.

This is the command that I use in Cron (it is saved as .sh script and its path pointed in Cron)

```
echo "Its" `date "+%l O clock now"` |  festival --tts
```

The problem is it doesn't work when music or video is playing, however after music is stopped or paused it announces the time.

I googled for it and found that in order to have multiple access to sound card one must use aoss (alsa-oss) I installed the required alsa-oss package and I modified the command as per the search results like this

```
echo "Its" `date "+%l O clock now"` | aoss festival --tts
```

but still it doesn't work and if I run the command with aoss it gives some error as below:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaoss.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
```

I don't know if this error is related to it somehow.

Someone on Reddit mentioned to use Alsa or Pulse-audio with festival and pointed me to [arch forums](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Festival#Usage_with_a_Sound_Server) which states that to use Alsa or Pulse-Audio we must edit the `~/.festivalrc` file, or `/usr/share/festival/festival.scm` and add some lines to it.

I added the lines mentioned in the link, but still it didn't solve my problem

Hence, I need help from you guys. Please help me correct this so that the time is announced by Cron even when music or video is playing.

Comment: It appears that there is inconsistency between your library and executable binary. You installed  either wrong architecture library or application.
Check out `file /sbin/init` if it prints 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: I did file /sbin/init the output was /sbin/init: symbolic link to `/lib/systemd/systemd' then i did file /lib/systemd/systemd I got this 
   /lib/systemd/systemd: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=ad47c3b45c2d2d67fabd4ef26ea02188c9197855, stripped

Answer (score 3):

As per this answer: [Can I use cron to chime at top of hour like a grandfather clock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832072/can-i-use-cron-to-chime-at-top-of-hour-like-a-grandfather-clock/832266#832266) you need to export an environment variable before playing sounds in your cron script:

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [Piper](https://github.com/rhasspy/piper)

*A fast, local neural text to speech system.* Check site project for installation, download of a voice and usage. For e.g.:

```sh
echo 'Welcome to the world of speech synthesis!' | \
  ./piper --model blizzard_lessac-medium.onnx --output_file welcome.wav
```

#### [**gTTS**](https://pypi.org/project/gTTS/)

> **gTTS** (*Google Text-to-Speech*), a Python library and CLI tool to interface with Google Translate's text-to-speech API. Write spoken mp3 data to a file, a file-like object (bytestring) for further audio manipulation, or `stdout`.

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
@hourly /usr/local/bin/gtts-cli -l en "Hour $(/bin/date +\%l)"  | /usr/bin/play -t mp3 - &> /dev/null
```

- Of course, change the text and language code to your desire.
- Where 1000 is the user `$UID`/`id -u`<sup>[1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio#Play_sound_from_a_non-interactive_shell_(systemd_service,_cron))</sup>.
- Installation: `pip install gtts`.

To use it inline: `@hourly export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"; /usr/local/bin/gtts-cli...`

Check also WaveNet based alternatives, like [wavenet_vocoder](https://github.com/r9y9/wavenet_vocoder)