# Can I use cron to chime at top of hour like a grandfather clock?

Tags: sound, scripts, cron

I get lost in askubuntu reading Q&A and experimenting with recommended code snippets. So I often miss switching TV news channels on the internet at the top of the hour. Not a big problem for youtube channels that allow time-shifting, but it's a "show stopper" for tv channels using flash player.

Can `cron` be configured to run a job at the top of each hour where I provide a script to sound a grandfather like clock chime (with subtle sound volume of course!)? A minor chime could be sounded at the bottom of the hour too. I'm sure I can locate suitable `.ogg` or `.oga` files on the net and I know I can use `ogg123` to play them. I just don't know if `cron` could do it. I know I could use a script that sleeps and wakes up to test time but don't like the thought of having something running all the time (there's enough of that going on already I think).

If this can be done with `cron` can someone answer how to set it up?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not very good at English idioms. _top of each hour_ meaning start of each hour?

Comment: @heemayl LOL yes. I come from a time before digital clocks were invented and there was a minute hand that when at "top" meant :00 of hour and when at "bottom" meant :30 of the hour. Hehe

Comment: sudo apt-get install mcron - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44470965/how-can-you-watch-gnuplot-realtime-data-plots-as-a-live-graph-with-automatic-up/44471008#44471008

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/mcron/manual/mcron.html#Top

Comment: @SDsolar this appears to be a replacement for `cron` which is beyond the scope of the question. FYI I've written the grandfather clock script in the answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[heemayl](https://askubuntu.com/users/216503/heemayl) has provided the correct answer to get `cron` to run at the top of the hour and bottom of the hour. **Thanks again!** However as other users have discovered a `cronjob` cannot play sound files by default:

- [How to make speaking clock ( via cron and festival tts) work while playing music](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621049/how-to-make-speaking-clock-via-cron-and-festival-tts-work-while-playing-music)
- [Help using crontab to play a sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719590/help-using-crontab-to-play-a-sound)

---

### Configuring `cron` to play sounds

In order for `cron` to play sound files it needs to `export` an environment variable:

```bash
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
```

Once this is done in your script sounds will play.

As pointed out by another answer **your** user ID may not always be `1000`. To find your user ID use:

```bash
$ id

uid=1000(rick) gid=1000(rick) groups=1000(rick),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),128(sambashare)
```

If your user ID is not 1000, then change the script to your ID.

#### Configure `cron` to run top of hour and bottom of hour

`crontab -e` setup (last 5 lines only):

```bash
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
00 *    *   *   *    /usr/local/bin/top-of-hour-chime    >/dev/null
00,30 * *   *   *    /usr/local/bin/bottom-of-hour-chime >/dev/null
```

Most users setup `cron` to use the `nano` editor. Use these control keys in `nano` to save your work:

- Add the last two lines above and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to write **O**ut (save) the file.
- A `/tmp...` filename is presented, but do not be concerned, simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Now use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to e**X**it the `nano` editor.

The `bottom-of-hour-chime` script runs at the top of the hour too but, that is OK since it's short and sweet.

If you don't have the `>/dev/null` at the end of the lines `cron` tries to email you with the command output. If you don't have the mail server setup an error message appears in your `/var/log/syslog` file:

```bash
Oct 02 10:00:07 dell CRON[21259]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

### Configuring `cron` to display pop-up notifications

The script  displays a pop-up notification message at the top of every hour. So for this an additional variable needs to be exported:

```bash
eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";
```

#### Contents of `top-of-hour-chime`

```bash
#! /bin/bash

# NAME: top-of-hour-chime
# PATH: /usr/local/bin
# DESC: Play sound called by cron
# CALL: Automatically called by /var/spool/cron/crontabs/<user_name>
# DATE: Created Oct 1, 2016. Modified June 10, 2018.
# UPDT: 2016-11-09 - Add notification bubble with time in text.
#       2018-06-10 - Switch from `ogg123` to `paplay` in default installation.

# exit # uncomment to suppress when watching movies

# paplay needs environment variable exported:
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"

# needed for notify-send
eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";

# get hour in 12 hour format
HOUR=$(date +%I)
ZHOUR=$(echo $HOUR | sed 's/^0*//')

pactl set-sink-volume 0 -25%
DISPLAY=:0 notify-send --urgency=critical --icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/status/appointment-soon.png "It is ""$ZHOUR"" o'clock"
paplay '/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/Melody piano.ogg'
pactl set-sink-volume 0 +25%
```

The `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR...` is necessary to get sound to play. This is because `cron` runs in minimal environment. This line should be omitted first if it you use a third party sound player. Then if no sound put the line back. Then still if no sound, well happy hunting!

The two main TV news shows I watch over the net have softer volume than normal so I have the TV turned up higher than normal. Consequentially when `ogg123` plays sound files they sound very loud. So `pactl` is used to reduce volume before chime and increase it afterwards.

#### Contents of bottom-of-hour-chime

This is almost a duplicate of `top-of-hour-chime` and perhaps redundant here, but included for full documentation purposes.

```bash
#! /bin/bash

# NAME: bottom-of-hour-chime
# PATH: /usr/local/bin
# DESC: Play sound called by cron
# CALL: Automatically called by /var/spool/cron/crontabs/<user_name>
# DATE: Oct 1, 2016. Modified June 10, 2018.

# UPDT: 2018-06-10 Switch from `ogg123` to `paplay` installed by default.

# exit # Uncomment to suppress when watching movies.

# paplay needs environment variable exported:
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"

pactl set-sink-volume 0 -25%
paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/Bliss.ogg
pactl set-sink-volume 0 +25%
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Steps followed, script runs, but still no sound.

Comment: @PaulFeakins When you call the script from the command line (not from within cron) are any error messages displayed? When cron is running what messages are showing up in `journalctl -xe` output.

Comment: I gave up, I'm just using this now instead: https://www.online-stopwatch.com/talking-clock-analog/

Comment: @PaulFeakins many people have problems getting `cron` working. I know I've had problems configuring it in the past. I'll look at creating a new script that simply sleeps until the top of the hour and bottom of the hour. The new script won't use `cron` at all. It's pretty low on the priority list though...

Comment: Yeah this is waaay more complicated than it should be. Perhaps using the right music player would solve it?

Comment: @PaulFeakins The whole point of the Q&A was to get `cron` to work to do something it doesn't natively do very well. If the point was "play a sound every hour" then `cron` would/should/could be the last choice. A sleeping script is the best choice.

Comment: WinEunuuchs2Unix the question was just how to get Linux to play a sound at a time interval. If you don't think cron is the best choice, you should add an answer with what you think is the best way to achieve that result. Cron was only mentioned as that is what the OP knows.

Comment: @PaulFeakins I'm wrote the both this accepted answer first and the question in October 2016 when I was just starting to learn Linux. Years later I wrote [multi-timer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039357/a-timer-to-set-up-different-alarms-simultaneosly) which I could modify to speak the time at the top of the hour.

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can.

Open your `cron` table with `crontab -e`, and add:

```
00 * * * * /path/to/player /path/to/file.ogg
```

Replace `/path/to/player`, and `/path/to/file.ogg` with respective values you want.

The above will play the sound (i.e. run the command), at every hour at `00`-th (start of first) minute.

If you want to run the command at `30`-th minute of each hour too:

```
00,30 * * * * /path/to/player /path/to/file.ogg
```

Comment: When typing `crontab -e` it says there is no file created for my user account. It offers to create one with `nano`. I did this and set up the commands suggested. When selecting `^W` (write file) the default file name is: `/tmp/crontab.6QN0vo/crontab`. The file name seems very wrong. Can you update your answer for creating a new `crontab -e` configuration file? Note my system is already setup to delete `/tmp/IG*` files over a day old which has been working well (I just don't remember how I set that puppy up).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Don't worry, `cron` opens that file temporarily in `/tmp`, once you save the content, will create/replace the file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username>`, and thats permanent.

Answer (score 3):

Despite using this export:

```
# paplay needs environment variable exported:
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
```

it didn't work.

After months of research found no solution.

In desperation, tried the following and it worked:

**Enter the following in contab**

```
# Terminal command: crontab -e
# Detect the name of the display in use
display=":$(ls /tmp/.X11-unix/* | sed 's#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##' | head -n 1)"
user=$(who | grep '('$display')' | awk '{print $1}') # the user of the display 
uid=$(id -u $user) #Detect the id of the user

XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/${uid}

*/5 * * * * sh /root/.play_sound.sh
```

Next create `.play_sound.sh`

**/root/.play_sound.sh**

```
display=":$(ls /tmp/.X11-unix/* | sed 's#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##' | head -n 1)"
user=$(who | grep '('$display')' | awk '{print $1}') # the user of the display 
uid=$(id -u $user) #Detect the id of the user

su - $user -c "paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga"
```

Hope this helps.