# How to keep speakers on?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My speakers are "smart", and after couple of hours of silence, they put themself to sleep. I've noticed in some mediacenter software (Kodi), there is an option to generate low-volume noise to keep the speaker on. Is there some similar option or some config parameter in Ubuntu?

Comment: So you need a sound to be played every hour? https://askubuntu.com/questions/832072/can-i-use-cron-to-chime-at-top-of-hour-like-a-grandfather-clock will do that but you need to find (or create) a very soft sound file.

Comment: Open terminal and run speaker-test -t sine -f 40 -c 2 for a 2 speaker set-up. At normal volume you'll hear a slight click from each speaker about every 10 seconds. If you don't want to hear that just turn the volume down. But it's enough to keep your speakers active. To stop it anytime, in terminal press Cntrl + c. – Paul Benson 30 mins ago