# How to play a sound in the background every 15 minutes?

Tags: command-line, cron

I have Polk Hampden speakers on my System76 desktop here.  The sound is great, but if no sound plays for ~15 minutes, it goes into a power saving mode where no sound plays until there is about 8 seconds of audio again.  So notifications, incoming calls etc. are all muted whether I want them to or not.

One guy [on the polkaudio forums](https://forum.polkaudio.com/discussion/comment/2139196/#Comment_2139196) created a script on Windows that plays a 20Hz tone for 10 seconds every 15 minutes that seems to fix the problem.

So I created a 20 Hz .mp3 that lasts for 15 seconds (`20Hz.mp3`), I installed `mpg123` and verified that this command works:

```
mpg123 ~/20Hz.mp3
```

What's the best way to execute this command in the background every 15 minutes?

Comment: I'm no expert on this, so likely this is not the 'best' way; yet I would possibly go for a shell script with a while loop in it, also with `sleep 900`. Then it would become possible to introduce this script as a service in systemd: https://askubuntu.com/a/1303177/1157519 That way probably it could be enabled / disabled as desired through systemctl. | Anyone reading this please feel free to educate me about what might be wrong with this.

Comment: @Levente I don't think there is anything wrong with this approach.

Answer (score 6):

If you can't reduce somehow those 8 seconds, you can generate a sound and play it periodically using user cron. There is no need of an external file.

1. Install sox, *Sound eXchange, the Swiss Army knife of audio manipulation*:

   ```
   sudo apt install sox
   ```
2. Edit your user cron table, *process scheduling daemon*:

   ```
   crontab -e
   ```
3. Add this to play a 10 second 20 Hz (hence, barely hearable) tone [every 15'](https://crontab.guru/every-15-minutes).

   ```
   */15 * * * *   XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 /usr/bin/play -n synth 10 sin 20
   ```

   Where 1000 is your user ID, the output of `id -u` or `$UID` environment variable.

Comment: This is awesome. I’m going to steal this idea and play a tone every 20 minutes to remind myself to stand up and stretch during the day. Thanks 

Comment: @Matigo You can play a nice sound like `play -q -n synth 2 pluck C5` or use [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1305584/349837)