# Searching for a Linux command to play an audio file in the background with ZERO volume

Tags: command-line, sound, volume-control, startup-applications

The reason I am doing this is that my bluetooth headset disconnects a few seconds after I stop any playing audio. I noticed that if I let cmus play something in a minimized terminal window with zero volume (the cmus volume, not the system volume), the headset stays connnected. I haven't found any other solution for this problem.

So to monkey-solve this, I have decided to find something which will play an audio file with zero volume, which I can set to autostart on boot in the background. I hope this will solve my issue of disconnecting bluetooth headset.

I found mpg123 but couldn't figure out how to set the volume of the playing audio file with command-line flags.

Laptop: xps 13 9365

PS: it happens on all distros I have tried. Currently I am on ubuntu 20.04.

PPS: it will be awesome if the command is light on CPU usage. Maybe some music files require less decoding and hence consume less power?

Any help will be super awesome! thank you!

Comment: This is super-related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1306563/1157519

Comment: This could be due to aggressive power saving settings, either with the Bluetooth device specifically or the USB bus. You might have better idle connection times by tweaking those values … 

Comment: @Matigo there are bluetooth speakers with this power-saving feature built-in, and there does not seem to be any user-facing way to configure it. I myself own such speakers (Creative T30). After 10 minutes of idle time, it turns itself off. (Thing is so extreme, that when connected with cable, but the input analog signal is _not loud enough_, it also counts as idle time. Very frustrating. Again, there seems to be no way to change any of this behavior.)